# Forcing Redis to Timeout

Tags: scala, playframework, redis, jedis

I am trying to force my redis client to timeout for testing purpose and I a fail to achieve so. I specify timeout to 2ms in my config and the set operation I perform takes > 2ms so why it does not timeout? Are these settings are kind of soft settings and not hard enforcement? I am using Jedis 2.6 and Scala 2.10 with Play 2.2.3

```
@Singleton
class RedisClient extends Cache {

  // set timeout
  val TIMEOUT = 2
  private val pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), getStringFromConfig("redis.url"), getIntFromConfig("redis.port"), TIMEOUT);

  def isOpen = pool.getNumActive()

  def set(key: String, value: String) = {
    isOpen match {
      case -1 => throw new Exception("Redis server is not running")
      case _ => {
        val jedis = pool.getResource()
        val before = Platform.currentTime
        jedis.set(key, value)
        println("TIME TAKEN " + (Platform.currentTime - before))
        pool.returnResource(jedis)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualy you do not need to test it but you may found answer in [Jedis sources](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/). TimeOut value used:

- as java socket connection timeout
- as [SO_TIMEOUT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_TIMEOUT) value. More info about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820874/what-is-the-functionality-of-setsotimeout-and-how-it-works).

To achieve goal in your test:

- Redis server should be heavy loaded during your test to not accept the connection. If you need connection timeout.
- Try to use some proxy to drop down connection perfomance (timeout by SO_TIMEOUT value).