# Default httpclient for resttemplate, have absolute value for read timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem where a application keeps blocking indefinitely on a post call made with a `RestTemplate` from Spring Boot.

```java
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(destination.getUri(), request, String.class);
```

We use the default standard JDK implementation and create it like this:

```java
    this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                       .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                       .setReadTimeout(5000)
                       .build();
```

Which sets the connection and read timeout to 5 seconds. But it seems this is not an absolute value, as soon as our application receives some bytes this read timeout resets and this causes our application to wait indefinitely.

I rather have an absolute read timeout where if you don't get the end response in less than 5 seconds the template throws an `TimeoutException`.

I couldn't find something like this in the options for the default client?

---EDIT---

I tried out @Peekay answer but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
           .setConnectionTimeToLive(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager())
           .build();

   HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
   clientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
   return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
```

I have also tried different implementations of the client's `RestTemplate` e.g. `HttpComponentsClientHttp`, `Netty4Client` and `OkHttp3Client` created them like so:

```
    Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    factory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
    return new RestTemplate(factory);
```

And tested them on a response that took longer than 5 seconds to respond. All of them except for Netty, which returned a `ReadTimeoutException`, had returned a 200 success. Unfortunately I cannot switch to that client, it seems you need to implement it yourself if you want to keep using the default client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we fixed this was by wrapping the `RestTemplate` REST call in a `CompletableFuture` and use the timeout functionality from that wrapper to kill the thread if it takes too long.

Here is an example:

```java
CompletableFuture<T> requestWrapper = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
  return restTemplate.postForEntity(/* Whatever arguments you need to pass */);
});

try {
  return requestWrapper.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
  requestWrapper.cancel(true);
  throw new TimeoutException("Endpoint took too long to respond, TimeoutException is triggered");
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  throw e.getCause();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right, you cannot setup absolute value and you have to interrupt the tread itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternate http clients with RestTemplate, such as the [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/) which gives you more control over how the connections are setup, pooled, and maintained:

- From its `HttpClientBuilder` you can set a Connection Time-to-Live which is the max TTL for the connection
- You can define a `RequestConfig` specifying a *connect timeout* (max time to wait for a connection to be established) and a separate *socket timeout* (max time a read() will wait for data).

For more details see: [setConnectTimeout vs. setConnectionTimeToLive vs. setSocketTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566851/setconnecttimeout-vs-setconnectiontimetolive-vs-setsockettimeout)

Answer (score 1):

```
-Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=<TimeoutInMiliSec>
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=<TimeoutInMiliSec>
```

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate/resttemplate-timeout-example/